# Как сделать редирект если заблокирована аналитика(трекер)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите не могу сделать редирект на другую страницу на своем сайте если у пользователя заблокирована аналитика?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function adBlockFunction() {
            document.getElementById('content').height { 
        window.location = 'https://vjqcfqn.ru'; 
    } 

</script>

<div id="content">
  <div>
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" onerror="adBlockFunction();"></script>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вот здесь ошибка синтаксиса (нет закрывающего знака `}` )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function adBlockFunction() {
            document.getElementById('content').height { 
        window.location = 'https://vjqcfqn.ru'; 
    } 

</script>
```

Не понятно что вы хотите сделать с объектом `content` и его высотой? Он разве тут нужен?

Ну и `window.location` для перенаправления надо заменить на `window.location.href`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adBlockFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://vjqcfqn.ru';
  }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Это должно сработать. Проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное заработало, Я не особо знаю и поэтому ошибаюсь в коде))) А если не трудно можно чтоб через заданное время этот редирект срабатывал ? Таймер поставить, если трекеры выключены то редирект через заданное время ? В любом случае спасибо огромное )))

Comment: @Helpsetup Рад помочь. Буду признателен за выбор ответа как верного и "стрелку вверх" (я тут ради репутации). По поводу таймера не совсем понял зачем это? Если аналитика не работает, то человека сразу отправит на другую страницу и никаких повторных редиректов не потребуется. Объясните подробнее чего хотите получить.

Comment: Человеку будет показано сообщение и потом редирект. Сообщение Я знаю как показать а как редирект через заданное время если включен блокировщик метрики не знаю (((

Comment: '<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout(function adBlockFunction() {
        window.location.href = 'https://dsfsdf.ru'; 
    } 2000);
</script>
 
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" onerror="adBlockFunction();"></script>'

Comment: Так он редиректит в любом случае даже если и трекер не блокируется

Comment: @Helpsetup поправил ответ, посмотрите. Это будет через секунду перенаправлять. Если нужно увеличить время - меняйте 1000 на нужное значение из рассчета 1000 = 1 секунда.